# When updating state in react, I'm getting undefined

Tags: reactjs

When I'm trying to update state in react application, I'm getting undefined as a result. I'm basically trying to remove an item from a list component, and trying to update the state, by getting the previous state. But when I try to remove the item, I'm getting undefined.

Now, I have this code:

```
const Checkout = () => {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [finalPrice, setFinalPrice] = useState(0);

  const { basketItems, setBasketItems } = useContext(ProductTypeContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    basketItems &&
      basketItems.forEach((id) => {
        axios
          .get(`http://localhost:6969/api/products/${id}`)
          .then((data) => {
            setProducts((prevState) => [...prevState, data.data.product]);
            setFinalPrice((prevState) => Number(prevState) + Number(data.data.product.price));
            setTimeout(() => {
              setLoading(false);
            }, 300);
          })
          .catch((err) => console.log(err));
      });
  }, []);

  if (loading) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div className="checkout-container">
        {products.map((product, index) => (
          <div key={index} className="checkout-products">
            <img src={product.img} width="100px" />
            <div>{product.name}</div>
            <div>{product.price}</div>
            <div>{product.taste}</div>
            <span
              onClick={() => {
                setBasketItems((prevState) => {
                  [...prevState, prevState.splice(index, 1)];
                });
              }}
            >
              X
            </span>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
      <div>Final Price: {finalPrice}</div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Checkout;
```

And I guess something is wrong when I click the X button, that is updating the state. Any sugesstions?

Comment: `Array.splice` doesn't return anything. It just makes suggested changes to the original array.

Comment: And if you want to "remove" items from the state, you'd probably want to avoid the `...prevState`, that would just spread the entire array into a new array.

Comment: And I just noticed that you don't have a return statement in the `setBasetItems` callback function. You need to return the new state from that function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The splice method returns the removed elements, not the modified array.

Update this part:

```
<span
onClick={() => {
    setBasketItems((prevState) => {
    const newState = [...prevState];
    newState.splice(index, 1);
    return newState;
    });
}}
>
X
</span>
```

**Note that:**  In your code, Final Price only updates when fetching data. You can create a function to calculate the final price based on the **current products** array and call it when removing an item.

Update Final Price Function:

```
const calculateFinalPrice = (products) => {
  return products.reduce((total, product) => total + Number(product.price), 0);
};
```

Use this function on our updated code:

```
<span
onClick={() => {
    setBasketItems((prevState) => {
    const newState = [...prevState];
    newState.splice(index, 1);
    return newState;
    });
    setFinalPrice((prevState) => calculateFinalPrice(prevState.splice(index, 1)));
}}
>
X
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

The approach I'd use to handle this is to use the `filter` method instead of `splice`.

I'll create a function called `removeProduct` with a param `productId` and then filter out that ID from the array.

// Note: You will have to adjust the code if the project doesn't have an ID. You will have to pass in a unique field and adjust it

```
const removeProduct = (productId) => {
    setBasketItems((ps) => ps.filter((item) => productId !== item.id));
 };
```

I'll also pass the function to the `onClick` of the `X` button.

```
<span onClick={() => removeProduct(product.id)}>
  X
</span>
```

Using `setTimeout` is not efficient in this usecase.

```
 setTimeout(() => {
   setLoading(false);
 }, 300);
```

Here's the complete code

```
const Checkout = () => {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [finalPrice, setFinalPrice] = useState(0);

  const { basketItems, setBasketItems } = useContext(ProductTypeContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    basketItems &&
      basketItems.forEach((id) => {
        axios
          .get(`http://localhost:6969/api/products/${id}`)
          .then((data) => {
            setProducts((prevState) => [...prevState, data.data.product]);
            setFinalPrice((prevState) => Number(prevState) + Number(data.data.product.price));
            setLoading(false);
          })
          .catch((err) => console.log(err));
      });
  }, []);

  const removeProduct = (productId) => {
    setBasketItems((ps) => ps.filter((item) => productId !== item.id));
  };

  if (loading) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div className="checkout-container">
        {products.map((product, index) => (
          <div key={index} className="checkout-products">
            <img src={product.img} width="100px" />
            <div>{product.name}</div>
            <div>{product.price}</div>
            <div>{product.taste}</div>
            <span
              onClick={() => removeProduct(product.id)}
            >
              X
            </span>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
      <div>Final Price: {finalPrice}</div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Checkout;
```

Comment: you don't want to address that `setTimeout(..., 300)`?

Comment: Nice spot. I didn't notice it as I was only focused on the OPs issue

Comment: Yes, thanks for pointing out. I removed the setTimeout

Comment: the issue with the update, `setLoading(false)` will be called when the first promise resolves, which means the `div` will begin rendering with impartial information. my impression of the `setTimeout` was that it was used to delay loading of all promises. Perhaps `Promise.all(...).then(setProducts).finally(_ => setLoading(false))` is what is needed?